# Infix to Postfix Stack C++ Output

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include "linkedStack.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "ArgumentManager.h"
using namespace std;


int getPrecedence(char ch) //this function will decide and return precedence for the operators and operand
{
    switch (ch) 
    {
    case '/':return 2;
    break;
    case '*': return 2;
    break;
    case '+': return 1;
    break;
    case '-': return 1;
    break;
    default: return 0;
    }
}


string infixToPostfix(const string& expression) // this function will convert the infix expression to postfix by passing the infix expression string

{
    int size = expression.size(); //size of infix string
    char infix[expression.size()]; //converting string into array of chars
    strncpy(infix, expression.c_str(), sizeof(infix)); 
    infix[sizeof(infix)] = '\0'; //adding 0 for array ending
    char postfix[strlen(infix)]; // create a char array with the size of the infix string length

    linkedStack s;
    int precedence;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char ch;
    //iterate the infix expression  
    while (i < size) 
    {
        ch = infix[i];
        //push opening parenthesis to stack
        if (ch == '(') 
        {
            s.push(ch);
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (ch == ')') 
        {
            while (!s.empty() && s.top() != '(') // if closing parenthesis is found pop of all the elements and append it to the postfix expression till we encounter an opening parenthesis
            {
                postfix[k++] = s.top();
                s.pop();
            }

            if (!s.empty()) 
            {
                s.pop(); // pop the opening parenthesis
            }
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        precedence = getPrecedence(ch);
        if (precedence == 0) 
        {
            postfix[k++] = ch; // if an operand is found add it to the postfix expression
        }
        else 
        {
            if (s.empty()) 
            {
                s.push(ch); //push operator onto stack if the stack is empty
            }
            else 
            {
                while (!s.empty() && s.top() != '(' && precedence <= getPrecedence(s.top())) // pop of all the operators from the stack to the postfix expression till we see an operator with a lower precedence than the current operator
                {
                    postfix[k++] = s.top();
                    s.pop();
                }

                s.push(ch);  // push the current operator to stack
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    while (!s.empty())          // pop all of the the remaining operators in the stack and add it to postfix 
    {
        postfix[k++] = s.top();
        s.pop();
    }

    postfix[k] = '\0'; // add null character to end of character array for c string
    string postfixStr = postfix; //covert the final postfix char array to a string
    return postfixStr;  // returns the final postfix expression as a string
}





int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    ArgumentManager am(argc, argv);
    string infilename = am.get("A");
    string outfilename = am.get("C");
    string expression1;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(infilename);
    if (infile.good())
    {
        getline(infile, expression1);       //gets the infix string from file
    }
    infile.close(); //close the infile stream

    string expression2 = "12 + 3 / 4";
    string postfix1 = infixToPostfix(expression1);
    string postfix2 = infixToPostfix(expression2);
    cout << expression1 << endl;
    cout <<  postfix1 << endl;
    cout <<  expression2 << endl;
    cout <<  postfix2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I'm having trouble with my output with my infix to post fix converter using stack. For instance in the case of "12 + 3 / 4" the output should be "12 3 4 / +" with the characters evenly spaced by one white space. However, it is adding unnecessary white spaces or none at all. For the test case above you can see the problem I'm running into in the attached pic or below. The first line is the infix the second is the post fix output. There are two cases here.[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvtEa.png)

```
25 + ( 4 * 5 ) - 12
25   4  5 * + 12-
12 + 3 / 4
12  3  4/+
```

Comment: What is the outcome when you used the debugger to step through your code?

Comment: One of the outcomes is 12  3  4/+. So it added two spaces in between 12,3,4 and no spaces before the operators.

Comment: [mcve], https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `infix[sizeof(infix)] = '\0';` writes out of bounds. If you have an array of size `N`, then accessing `array[N]` is always wrong.

Comment: Do not use `strncpy`. It is made of sadness and deception. (If you ever actually need what `strncpy` does, replace it by `memcpy` and `memset`.)

Comment: Why do you think that the spacing will magically be correct? You never check whether the input character is a space, so it is just treated as part of the operand. That makes your operands ` 3 ` and ` 4 `, so when you write one followed by the other, there are two consecutive spaces. "Running" the program with a pencil and a pad of paper would show you that.

Comment: Also, all that fooling around with (non-standard) variable length arrays and incorrect string copying which @melpomene is complaining about could be avoided by simply using the input string as it id. You're not modifying it; why do you neef a copy? You can, if necessary, index a C++ string just like a C `char` array, but really it would simplify your code to use a "range for" instead of indexing: `for (const char& ch: expression) { ... }`. That will fix at least one bug in your parser.

Comment: Dear Rici, in the end I did realize it was reading in the blank spaces as operands, but I couldn't figure out how to ignore those. So I solved the problem using a different method that I posted as the answer.

Comment: @MChung93: The easiest way to ignore the whitespace would be to just ignore it :) (`if (ch == ' ') continue;` would work if you had a sensible loop.) Adding spaces after every operand and operator seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the advice. In the end I did a few things to achieve the desired output. First, I increased the postfix array. Next, in two certain spots in the loop, whenever it appended to the postfix array I would also add a space.

Here:

```
while (!s.empty() && s.top() != '(' && precedence <= getPrecedence(s.top())) // pop of all the operators from the stack to the postfix expression till we see an operator with a lower precedence than the current operator
                {
                    postfix[k++] = s.top();
                    postfix[k++] = ' ';
                    s.pop();
                }
```

And here:

```
while (!s.empty())          // pop all of the the remaining operators in the stack and add it to postfix 
    {
        postfix[k++] = s.top();
        postfix[k++] = ' ';
        s.pop();
    }
```

Lastly, I used a separate function to trim any extra spaces in the final string.
A little messy but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

1) This code :

```
int size = expression.size(); //size of infix string
char infix[expression.size()]; //converting string into array of chars
strncpy(infix, expression.c_str(), sizeof(infix)); 
infix[sizeof(infix)] = '\0'; //adding 0 for array ending
```

could be replaced by :

```
char * infix = new char [expression.length()+1];
std::strcpy (infix, expression.c_str());
```

2) This code pop values without repush them into s after.

```
while (!s.empty() && s.top() != '(' && precedence <= getPrecedence(s.top())) // pop of all the operators from the stack to the postfix expression till we see an operator with a lower precedence than the current operator
{
     postfix[k++] = s.top();
     s.pop();
}
```